# Window always visible when scrolling on a website?

Tags: html, scroll, window

sometimes there are sites that have some small information window thats always visible when I scroll the page. Its always on the left side and centered for example. Hows that called and are there some examples somewhere?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this guide, it uses jquery and css in order to do it, but seems simple enough.

http://nn.pe/07rglq

Comment: Is that available as wordpress plugin by any chance?

Comment: You should have said it was for Wordpress =) I'm sure if you search in the plugin section you will find something, try "follow sidebar" as a search string and see what you can find.

Comment: Yeah :D ... thing is, I dont need it for the wordpress sidebars, I need it per post/article. When writing an article, I need a way to define what the box contains and make it post/article related, know what I mean?